# 'Don't know how to build task' error in Capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to learn to use Capistrano 3 by following the DOCS and I've written a simple task to test my understanding.

The **task** is created in the default `task` dir in `lib/capistrano/tasks`:

```
  desc "Check status of web server"
    task :nginx_status do
      on roles(:web) do |host|
        execute 'service nginx status'
      end
    end
```

My `config/deploy/staging.rb` file contains the following:

```
set :stage, :staging

role :web, "192.168.0.11"
role :app,  "192.168.0.11"
role :db, "192.168.0.11", primary:true

server '192.168.0.11', user: 'vagrant', roles: %w{web app}
```

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

My `deploy.rb` contains an app name and a repo url to github.

When I run `cap staging nginx_status` I get the following error:

```
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'nginx_status'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/H/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

I also noticed that if I ran `cap -vT` the task `nginx_status` is not in the list(?)

On a side note, **are SSH keys a must** to connect to remote servers?

### UPDATE 1

I found that if I place my task in `config/deploy.rb` it works. So the question I now have is how do you run tasks from the task dir?

### UPDATE 2

So as per the **Capfile** the `tasks` dir is looked at by the following:

```
# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

So I changed  the task extension to `.rake` and it worked. However the documentation says it should be `.cap`

["We'll dive into those more later, but add those lines to a file in ./lib/capistrano/tasks, call it something like access_check.cap"](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/cold-start/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Take a look at this commit.](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/7e41233d76fec0aca6877b62b876b7e2c9b85ec0)

They've switched from `.cap` to `.rake` 3 months ago.

The whole idea is to make `capistrano3` fully `rake-compatible`. Just use `.rake` extension for you tasks.